# Cannot connect to Pixy with ev3dev

Tags: python, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I have a pixy 2 that I'm trying to connect with the following code

```
pixy = Sensor(address=INPUT_1)
assert pixy.connected, "Connecting PixyCam"
```

Unfortunately I cannot connect to my Pixy 2 and don't really know what to do.

Connecting to a

```
TouchSensor(address=INPUT_4)
```

works fine. But not when I try with Pixy 2

I've found the code from here:
https://www.ev3dev.org/docs/tutorials/using-pixy-camera/

Do anyone know what I can do? See picture for error code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ev3Dev does not support Pixy 2 so I had to use Python SMBUS. And it worked.